# AVAudioPlayer fadeDuration "jumps" when called again before completed

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have an `AVAudioPlayer` that fades in from silence over 3 seconds.  To accomplish that, before creating the player I set its volume to 0, start it, then immediately set the fadeDuration:

```
somePlayer.setVolume(0.0, fadeDuration: 0.0) 
somePlayer.play()
somePlayer.setVolume(1.0, fadeDuration: 3.0)
```

Works great.

I would like the ability to fade the player back to 0.0 before it's completed fading up; for example if a track is fading in and the user changes their mind, they can immediately "stop" it and it will fade back out cleanly.  However, when I call

`somePlayer.setVolume(0.0, fadeDuration: 3.0)`

on that same `AVAudioPlayer` instance it "jumps" all the way to 1.0 before starting to fade out, as if the method just ran the entire fade-in instantly.

Is there a way to prevent that "jump" from happening?  Running it through something like `AVAudioEngine` won't work, as I'm looking to create multiple tracks that can individually be faded in and out.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but this could be related to your problem:
http://blog.ericd.net/2019/05/09/avaudioplayer-setvolume-with-fading-properly/